# ASP 5 MVC 6 (RC1) - Web API with EF 6 works locally but not deployed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Web API I created in ASP 5 MVC 6 (FULL CLR). The web API references a standard .net class library, which has the entity framework 6 NUGET package installed. If I launch the web api locally (IIS express) and then try to run a method which contacts the database, everything works fine.

When I deploy the web API (I set it up in IIS), using the "Publish" command, to my DEV server (Windows Server 2012) and try to contact the same method, but on the server, I get the following exception (any other method that doesn't touch the database works):

```
{
   "$id":"1",
   "ClassName":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException",
   "Message":"Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, 
Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.",
   "Data":null,
   "InnerException":null,
   "HelpURL":null,
   "StackTraceString":"   
     at CMAllocation.Web.Data.InvestorRulesRepository..ctor()\r\n
     at CMAllocation.Web.CMAllocationWebApi.Controllers
        .InvestorRulesController.GetInvestors() 
     in E:\\CMAllocation\\WebServices\\CMAllocationWebApi
          \\Debug\\approot\\src\\CMAllocation.Web.CMAllocationWebApi
          \\Controllers\\InvestorRulesController.cs:line 45",
   "RemoteStackTraceString":null,
   "RemoteStackIndex":0,
   "ExceptionMethod":
     "1\n.ctor\nCMAllocation.Web.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
      PublicKeyToken=null\nCMAllocation.Web.Data.InvestorRulesRepository\nVoid .ctor()",
   "HResult":-2147024894,
   "Source":"CMAllocation.Web.Data",
   "WatsonBuckets":null,
   "FileNotFound_FileName": "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, 
      Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
   "FileNotFound_FusionLog":
      "WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.\r\n
       To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value 
       [HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.\r\n
       Note: There is some performance penalty associated with 
       assembly bind failure logging.\r\n
       To turn this feature off, remove the registry value 
       [HKLM\\Software\\Microsoft\\Fusion!EnableLog].\r\n"
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE** I can clearly see the EF 6 dll's in the approot/packages folder:
[image: Here is an image of the packages in my app root]

Comment: No one has anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your server is missing `'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'` or one of its dependencies.

- Build on the server with [`msbuild`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx).
- Run NuGet restore. [Dave Ebbo has a good article.](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html) It is [`nuget restore`](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference) from the cmd line.
- If that doesn't work, install the `EntityFramework` package into the GAC on your server.

Comment: I guess it depends on the way he deploy the application on server. Perhaps missing something when publish it?

Comment: It looks like your using dynamic compilation, because otherwise the build would have found the missing assembly. Have you tried precompiling it instead of using dynamic compilation?

Comment: In my app root I can clearly see that the publisher is moving over the entity framework 6 dll's. See my original post for an image of my app root/package folder.